# XAMPP MYSQL UNEXPECTED SHUTDOWN. I have tried every solution I have seen so far

Tags: mysql, xampp

Mysql in XAMPP starts and the crashes unexpectedly after a few seconds. I have tried ever solution that I have seen on this website and others and I cannot seem to fix it. Can anyone tell me what is wrong please?

The following is my error message:

```
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-06-07 18:43:59 17e0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Binlog end
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-06-07 18:43:59 172 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Please help because I am about to give up.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: @OllyTenerife Multiple times. It hasn't helped.

Comment: tried all theses: http://webdevelopmentscripts.com/23-solved-innodb-error-space-header-page-consists-of-zero-bytes-xampp

Comment: @Dagon I haven't seen solution 2 before but I tried it and it still doesn't work

Comment: there are other LAMP stacks, perhaps you would have better luck with one of them, and or install each separately

Comment: @Dagon I am hoping I can get this to work because much of this is going over my head as I am a complete beginner to mysql and the like

Comment: did you do anything to your mysql install after you initialized it ? as in change the my.cnf? or datadirectory?

Comment: Try running as Admin or in compatible with a lower version of windows.